# conditions in div in view layer in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using razor in my view layer, in my following code, I have to add that `if(Model.DateModel.DateOnHold.HasValue ===1)` then my date should turn into red color and its format should change to this -yyyy-mm-dd- from yyyy-mm-dd .
The code that is existing where I have to add this one condition is given below:-

```
<div class= col-lg-12>
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.DateModel.Date)
    @Html.ValidationFor(p => p.DateModel.Date)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DateModel.Date, (Model.DateModel.Date != null && Model.DateModel.Date.HasValue ? Model.DateModel.Date.Value.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") : ""),new{@class = "form-control"})
<div>
```

As per my requirement there is some `dateOnHold` is selected from database the date should turn into red color.
`DateModel` is a model from where I am accessing Date and `DateOnHold` variable. This is an MVC application

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi perhaps change the class name if the condition is met?

Comment: How can I do that, Can you provide a example please

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your help but this code is highlighting my textbox with black but there is no chance in date

Comment: @freedomn-m I am sorry for my mistake, actually that is textbox not label, I updated that in my question. Once again, I am really sorry